# how to get list of registered targets in AWS target group via CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-ecs, aws-elb

We are trying to get the state of a registered target (instance) in a target group.  This can be done with the command `aws elbv2 describe-target-health --target-group-arn ${TG} --targets Id=${ID},Port=${PORT}`, [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/describe-target-health.html).  We are able to get the PORT via the `aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster $CLUSTER --tasks $task` command, [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-tasks.html).  But how can the target's instance Id be retrieved via CLI?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This will give you the array of registered instance ID in a target group. When you have target ARN why you using target ID? so I am skipping target ID and using just target ARN.

```
aws elbv2 describe-target-health --target-group-arn ${TG}  --query 'TargetHealthDescriptions[*].Target.Id'
```

Comment: this command will list down both `"State": "unused"` and `"State": "healthy"` instances. What if I want to list down healthy instances only?

Comment: @Alfred then you should parse the output for your use case.

Comment: Alfred: you can print the state of the instances like this:

aws elbv2 describe-target-health --target-group-arn "${TG}" --query 'TargetHealthDescriptions[*].[Target.Id,TargetHealth.State]' --output text