# How to get Target group of running EC2 instances using AWS API's

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying to write a lambda where I have requirement to get all running instances from the target group. Once I have instance ID we need to get the meta-data about that instance and set those values into the lambda. In order to start I have looked at AWS SDK documentation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTargetGroups.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/examples-ec2-instances.html
But I am not sure if this a correct way to start with my problem.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Although the question contains all the details required, it is always better to specify the exact language you are working on, so others can provide more value.

Comment: Sure I am looking for solution in JAVA

Answer (score 1):

Here's some examples for Python, but there are matching commands in every AWS SDK for other languages.

Based on advice from [how to get list of registered targets in AWS target group via CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52022365/174777), you can obtain a list of instances registered to a Target Group with [`describe_target_health()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.describe_target_health). It will return a list of targets, including the Instance ID:

```json
{
    'TargetHealthDescriptions': [
        {
            'Target': {
                'Id': 'i-0f76fade',
                'Port': 80,
            },
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

You could then call [`describe_instances()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) to obtain information about each instance. To make things quicker, you can **pass multiple Instance IDs to the `describe_instances()` call** to obtain information about all instances from a single API call.